# What is $\frac{d^2E}{dt^2} , \frac{d^3E}{dt^3} , \frac{d^2B}{dt^2}$?

Tags: calculus

Simply, -someone on my forum quoted some calc. equations and I need to know how to understand them.

What is $\frac{d^2E}{dt^2} , \frac{d^3E}{dt^3} , \frac{d^2B}{dt^2}$?

The context of the forum is:

> In calculus, we might say the rise-time of spike is a manifestation like $\frac{d^2E}{dt^2}$ and even $\frac{d^3E}{dt^3}$, similar to "jerk" with a change in the acceleration of a car. Since you also mention current, maybe there is a manifestation like $\frac{d^2B}{dt^2}$ ? would you like to comment ? Is the corner ringing related to $\frac{d3E}{dt3}$ ?

I fully know the theory that is being discussed if there are any questions but what does the math mean please ?

Comment: $E$ is likely a function representing the position of something.  Not too sure about $B$ though.

Comment: What are $B$ and $E$?  Magnetic and electric fields, maybe?

Comment: Yes. E field and B field.

Comment: I dunno. Is he talking about delta's.  delta E field/delta time ?

Comment: Either second and third derivatives of Electric and magnetic fields (unlikely) or partial derivatives of components of those fields?

Comment: These are $2$nd and $3$rd derivatives with respect to time. I think you'd need to know more context to know what they mean and what the variables represent so I'd ask the person who wrote it.

Comment: Yes to 2nd and 3rd derivatives w/respect to time, makes sense. We are talking about the "Gibbs Phenomenon " leading edge rise spike overshoot (or ringing present if not damped) on a square wave, if that helps.

Comment: But now what is the difference between 2nd and 3rd derivatives ? Why are we numbering derivatives ?

Comment: When you say d-squared; are we indicating a non-linearity ?

Comment: The editing is great. Makes sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the lack of given context, I will give the most general answer I can.

What you seem to be describing is the Leibniz notation for derivatives. For example, we can have an original function $E$, and its first derivative $E'$, second derivative $E''$, and third derivative $E'''$. Leibniz notation is another way of writing derivatives such as these. In your case, $\frac{d^2E}{dt^2}$ refers to the second derivative $E''$ of the function $E$, $\frac{d^3E}{dt^3}$ refers to the third derivative of the function $E$, and $\frac{d^2B}{dt^2}$ refers to the second derivative of the function $B$.

In this case, the 'jerk' mentioned in the text refers to $\frac{d^3S}{dt^3}$, the third derivative of the position/displacement function $S$, and the 'acceleration' refers to $\frac{d^2S}{dt^2}$, the second derivative of the position/displacement function $S$. These bear similarities to the derivatives with the function $E$ mentioned above, just with a different function, $S$.